# FontAwesome [Webpack] not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

I'm currently developing my Cortana-App and have a big problem with FontAwesome :)
Since I recently switched to React + Redux and Webpack [Better Structure + Less Space] I had to everything new.

And now comes the problem, I can't use FontAwesome properly. It just displays a white square... I checked many topics on this [Directory Issues, not properly set up webpack-loader], but didn't found anything that fixed the problem. No errors in console of webpack, no errors in developer console.

Here's the link to my project:
https://github.com/khayalan-mathew/gymdonapp/tree/feature/react-redux
The ReactElement i use font-awesome in is:
https://github.com/khayalan-mathew/gymdonapp/blob/feature/react-redux/src/components/test.jsx

I hope somebody can help me :) If you have found the right solution please send a pullrequest or write it down below

-Mathew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue from [css-loader generating wrong file paths](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/280). This won't happen in production build, but still annoying when it render squares in development mode.

Until this issue is fixed, you can disable css-loader source map to see the font rendered correctly in development. Find somewhere in your webpack config that write `css?sourceMap` and change it to `css`.

Comment: You are my hero :)